# Is there a successful formula/algorithm for Hangman?

Tags: probability, python

I am trying to create an 'AI' engine to play hangman, Version 2 won every 1 in 5 games, it achieved this via frequency analysis of a list of 12500 words and then picking the highest frequency each time (so it would always pick the exact same letters. However I thought I had just finished version 3 which would use frequency analysis on the full 12500 list and it would then filter that list depending on whether the letter was in it or not and perform the same process - so each time the list will get smaller and in theory the analysis will be more accurate as it is using the frequency for possible words.

However after running my code until 100 wins, I have now found it only wins between 1 in 8 and 1 in 10 times. So it has definitely got less accurate.

Note: the word the engine chooses is from the initial list

There are two possibilities for this:

1. My theory that filtering the list would yield a higher accuracy was wrong
2. I have made an error in my code

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Let's get this straight. Suppose after four turns you have tried O, B, T, and G, hitting two B's and one G, like this: `_ _ B B _ G _` So now you discard all words that have O or T in them anywhere, and all words that don't have the exact same pattern of B's and G's. Then for each untried letter, count the number of words containing that letter; and pick the letter with the highest word score. Is this right? If so, I don't see how that could make things worse.

Comment: All letters are 5 letter words! So the highest frequency letter is 'E', if the word contains the letter the 'E' it changes the list to 5500 words (all of which contain the letter 'E') if it's not in the list then it uses the remaining 7000 list to perform a new frequency calculation and so on until it reaches 0 lives or it guesses 5 correct letters (accounted for multiple letters)

Comment: Okay I think you're right, (thankfully the word contained a 'Y') so my list only had 40 words and it looks like isn't using the frequency count on the new list. Once I've fixed it I'll comment the new probability of it winning!

Comment: If the word contains the letter 'E', then you know _where_ the letter 'E' appears (assuming this is [traditional, pencil-and-paper hangman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangman_(game)) that we're talking about). So you can narrow the list down to far fewer than 5500 words.

Comment: Ah yes, you're absolutely right! I guess that will be version 4 once I get this count working properly and see what the new probability is! I am hoping I can get it to win 90% of all games as I know frequency analysis will completely fail with words containing 'Z' etc.

Comment: "I won 1000. I lost 2123 times" - finally got the frequency to calculate and filter properly. Think I am going to try your idea at the weekend, should see it get very close to winning every game I imagine.

Comment: How many turns do you get? And what is your word list? I'm curious because I implemented Hangman myself for an 8-bit microcontroller with 512 bytes of RAM, about 35 years ago. I got paid for it too!

Comment: Wow that sounds way more hi-tech than what I am doing! I copied all 5 letter words from bestwordlist.com into a CSV file. You have 8 lives, I initially started with 7, but read the rules and it's fairly standard to have 8.